# Unable to successfully redirect to https://apps.facebook.com/MYAPPNAME on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, mobile

Facebook canvas site
Ruby on Rails 3.0.7
OmniAuth 0.3.0 (server side authentication)

On a successful Facebook authentication, when Facebook invokes my Omniauth callback action, my app. redirects to the URL "http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME".

On the desktop, this displays my application inside of the Facebook iframe as per normal for canvas apps. The redirect to "http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME" results in a call to "/facebook/canvas" on my app, and it moves forward from there.

On any mobile platform (iOS, Android), I get the error "The mobile version of the app "Redflag Dev Staging" is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access." No call is ever made back to my app.

I've done a fair bit of Googling on this to try and figure out what the problem is.

Many suggested that my "Mobile Site URL" needed to be different than my "Site URL" in the app settings. I have changed the "Mobile Site URL" value to a couple of different things and get the same result.

I am happy to make whatever changes to my app settings that might be required, but I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to help.

Is there a mobile equivalent of "apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME" that I should be redirecting to when servicing mobile requests?

Any insight is appreciated.

Wes

Comment: have you got any answer ? please share it.

Comment: No I've never figured this one out.